# Open iOS app after accepting Facebook apprequest

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm just trying to open any iOS app installed (and I say any, because I can't open any of them) in my iPhone after accepting a facebook apprequest I send from my Facebook App. The purpose is to check the behaviour of opening an installed app.

Currently, I just can open the appstore with an app store id (I put instagram one for example), but in Bundle ID, I wrote: com.burbn.instagram (which is the bundle id according to this: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup?bundleId=com.burbn.instagram, and in URL Scheme suffix is blank because I don't know what to set.

I just want to open an installed app after accepting an app request, I'm a newbie and I'd prefer to do this before programming my Facebook iOS app.

Thanks.